# Energy, mass and vacuum relationship

Tags: condensed-matter, matter

We know that energy equals mass accelerated to squared lightspeed.

We can only observe energy as the effect it has on mass. It is not possible to define Energy on it´s own in space time. All measurements of energy collapse the wavefunction to accelerated matter having momentum and energydensity expressed only as properties of matter relating to it´s surroundings.

Energy in itself is defined as non-physical, nonexisting in spacetime. Where there is spacetime there is always mass, and were there is mass, Energy is transformed into matter in a state of c^2.

The property of energy that separates it from mass is that energy doesen´t exist, right?

And mass is a property of energy when it interferes with itself, therefore the squared lightspeed, since reflected energy propagating in opposite directions produce a local volume of mass, a bubble in spacetime.

If expanding energy meets a larger opposing force, we would have squared light speed, right?

If energy cannot be observed in itself and the definition of mass separates energy and matter by being observable in spacetime, the vacuum of space have the same properties as energy. Both vacuum and energy is impossible to observe, as observation inevitably involves mass, and where there is mass there is no energy, and where there is mass there is no vacuum.

If stars and planets are considered as charges, they don´t radiate into vacuum, they only transfer energy as radiation towards mass of lower energy. Energy doesn´t exist in spacetime without potential in a well, and only emerges as mass accelerated to c^2. This would make the vacuum infinite energy and matter would relate to the vacuum as a sink or well, surrounded by pressure of energy limited to only exist as points with potential in matter. The sink consists of geometrical expansion through a point stretching over time to a line, continuing expansion to a plane that expands into a volume. All matter is threedimensional geometry, but it relates to all other matter moving in relation to each other, and the geometrical shape expands it´s existance by inhabiting increasing volumes of space over time. Each new dimension being relative motion of larger groups of matter moving together, like a planet in a solar system and a solar system in a galaxy.

Energy and vacuum has the same properties, is there a reason for them not being the same thing?